# How to use the 'flatmap' operator conditionally ? (Angular 2/rxjs)

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, rxjs, rxjs5, flatmap

What I'm trying to achieve is to run a series of observables conditionally.

```
return observable.map(response => response)
       .flatmap(response1 => observable1(response1))
       .flatmap(response2 => observable2(response2))
       .flatmap(response3 => observable3(response3))
```

I need to check the response1 and invoke the remaining observables if needed, else I need to return response1 and break the execution and so on.

I've gone through the following SO questions but they doesn't seem to answer my question

> [Conditionally choose observable in RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273065/conditionally-choose-observable-in-rxjs)
>
> [RXJS if with observable as conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34728827/rxjs-if-with-observable-as-conditional)
>
> [Handle Error in RxJs flatMap stream and continue processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946077/handle-error-in-rxjs-flatmap-stream-and-continue-processing)

I'm new to rxjs, so forgive me if the question seems too lame.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the condition based on? Is it static, does it depend on `response`, does the second condition depend on `response2` etc?

Comment: yes, the condition is static, the second condition depends on the `response2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is like calling multiple consecutive HTTP requests where results depend on each other. This is where you want to use `concatMap()` instead because it'll wait until the Observable returned from the callback function completes.

It's hard to tell what exactly you want to do from your description but if you need to stop propagating the results (and avoid calling unnecessary HTTP requests) have a look `takeWhile()` operator or simple `filter()` operators.

With `filter()`:

```
return observable
    .concatMap(response => response)
    .filter(response1 => response1.whatever === true)
    .concatMap(response1 => observable1(response1))
    .filter(response2 => response2.whatever === true)
    .concatMap(response2 => observable2(response2))
    .filter(response3 => response3.whatever === true)
```

This simply won't propagate the item further if it fails the `filter` test. However the source `observable` can still emit values that'll go through the chain. In other words the `filter` operator doesn't complete the chain.

With `takeWhile()`:

```
return observable
    .concatMap(response => response)
    .takeWhile(response1 => response1.whatever === true)
    .concatMap(response1 => observable1(response1))
    .takeWhile(response2 => response2.whatever === true)
    .concatMap(response2 => observable2(response2))
    .takeWhile(response3 => response3.whatever === true)
```

If any of the `takeWhile()` result into false it'll complete the chain and no other value can be emitted.

Comment: What's the difference between `concatMap` and the `flatMap` that the OP is using?

Comment: I want to stop the propagation to `observable2` if `response1` is a certain value and return `response1` or else run `observable2` and so on

Comment: can you show an example how to stop propagation using `filter()` or `takewhile()`

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
observable.map(res => res.json())
  .flatMap(json => {
      if (json.something === 'something') {
          return this.http.get('/anotherCall')
              .map(res => 'second response: ' + res);
      } else {
          return Observable.from(['just return something else']);
      }
  });
```

It's only two calls but you get the point.

Comment: Note : the 'return something else' can  be `Observable.empty()` if you want the streams to complete immediately there. You cannot just *not* return some observable-like thing, this will cause an runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find easy way to bypass operators, if you decide to skip n last operators, you still have to pass last valid response through all operators:

```
 return observable
   .flatmap(r => {
        return r.value > 1 ? observable1(r) : Observable.of(r);
   })
   .flatmap(r => {
        return r.value > 2 ? observable2(r) : Observable.of(r);
   })
   .flatmap(r => {
        return r.value > 3 ? observable3(r) : Observable.of(r);
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can combine all the observables into one single observable and subscribe to that as below,

```
return response
         .concatMapTo(response1,(response2, response3) => 
             `${response2} ${response3}`
          );
```

Subscribe to it using

```
data = response.subscribe(val => console.log(val)); // contains all three responses value
```

Still you can access each one separately using the `response2` and `response3` named instance.

**Subscribing for a single object using different observables:**
If you are looking to combine data and properties from different observables you can have a look at this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352507/rxjs-angular-how-to-zip-observable-arrays-of-objects/42352720#42352720)**

Comment: I don't want to combine the responses, I only need to run `observable2` if I want to.

Comment: you can return separately then? why you are using **flatMap**?

Comment: or what else will I use if I want to run `observable2` if the `response1` is a certain value or return `response1` if it is some other value without nesting