# RxJS 6 - flatMap condition

Tags: javascript, flatmap, rxjs6

I have a form that creates an item in the backend, and optionally another resource depending if the user selects a checkbox. The second resource has to be created only after the first one is. I have come up with this code, but I don't think it's the right way to do it, especially the part where the checkbox hasn't been checked and I have to return a nonsense Observable. Any help?

```
this.myService.createArticle(article)
  .flatMap(_ => {
    if (this.checkbox) {
      return this.mailer.createOtherResource(data);
    } else {
      return Observable.of('done');
    }
  });
```

I also tried returning an EmptyObservable, but it doesn't work.

Comment: This looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705511/how-to-use-the-flatmap-operator-conditionally-angular-2-rxjs Although it's rxjs2, it should be applicable to rxjs6 as well

Comment: Sorry for the late answer! Yep, you are right, `filter()` or `takeWhile()` is what I was looking for. Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the 'flatmap' operator conditionally ? (Angular 2/rxjs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705511/how-to-use-the-flatmap-operator-conditionally-angular-2-rxjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if this question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705511/how-to-use-the-flatmap-operator-conditionally-angular-2-rxjs), there are some differences due to RxJS version. In RxJS 6 this would be done similarly to this:

```
this.myService.createArticle(article)
  .pipe(
    filter(() => this.checkbox),
    flatMap(() => return this.mailer.createOtherResource(data)),
  });
```

Comment: Why adding the underscore parameter if it's not being used?